# parsing data to an external file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

I have a sample array of structs like this

```
var array = 
[ {item1: 'john', item2: 'micheal'},
  {item1: 'joe', item2: 'mich'},
  {item1: 'jo', item2: 'mi'},
]
```

I try to parse all these objects (900 objects in this array) into another file
using this code

```
const fs = require('fs');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('file.txt');
const pathName = writeStream.path;
   
// write each value of the array on the file breaking line
array.forEach(value => writeStream.write(`${value}\n`));

// the finish event is emitted when all data has been flushed from the stream
writeStream.on('finish', () => {
   console.log(`wrote all the array data to file ${pathName}`);
});

// handle the errors on the write process
writeStream.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(`There is an error writing the file ${pathName} => ${err}`)
});

// close the stream
writeStream.end();
```

However when open the file I get

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

which is not what I want. I want to see

```
{item1: 'john', item2: 'micheal'},
  {item1: 'joe', item2: 'mich'},
  {item1: 'jo', item2: 'mi'},
```

which is not what I see. How can I correct this?

Comment: try to pass value to JSON `writeStream.write(`${JSON.stringify(value)}\n`));`

Comment: Or forego the loop and say: `writeStream.write(JSON.stringify(array));`